# General relativity without curvature?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, differential-geometry, field-theory, curvature

Is there a reformulation of general relativity without curved space time, just with fields (like classical E&M)?

Edit: removed the part about E&M with curvature (multiple posts).

Answer (score 4):

The Gauge Theory of Gravity ([GTG](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory_gravity)) by Lasenby, Doran and Gull has a background spacetime with fields on it.

It is basically derived from the same physical principles but as a background theory. It ends up not being the same theory, for instance it doesn't have the same isotropic solutions, and I think it does not allow time travel and such (unlike General Relativity).

There are others as well.

Answer (score 2):

GR can be recast into an equivalent but conceptually quite different form, using [teleparallel gravity](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0011087v1). This approach introduces the Weitzenboeck connection, which has no curvature, but has torsion. The presence of torsion indicates that gravity is *not geometrized*. Recall that in GR, we can always choose a locally inertial coordinate system such that the geodesic equation is simply $$\frac{d^2 x^{\mu}}{d\tau^2}=0,$$ since there is a reference frame in which all Christoffel symbols vanish - this is the weak equivalence principle. However, this implies that in the same frame, $${T^{\sigma}}_{\mu\nu}={\Gamma^{\sigma}}_{\mu\nu}-{\Gamma^{\sigma}}_{\nu\mu}=0$$
and therefore this tensor vanishes in all frames. In Teleparallel gravity this is false, so gravity is a force represented by the nonvanishing symbols. That is, it's a field. The approaches are equivalent. Check out the link at the beginning for more.